# xpath to retrieve a name /text

Tags: selenium, xpath

Hello and thanks for reading the post. From the code below I am trying to verify student name

```
<td id="cphPageContent_ChildrensInfo1_repChildren_hasEnrollments_0"><a href="#fDTluXIJ9PY=" class="editStudent">Rahman, Zayan </a><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphPageContent$ChildrensInfo1$repChildren$ctl01$hidChildID" id="cphPageContent_ChildrensInfo1_repChildren_hidChildID_0" value="fDTluXIJ9PY="></td>
```

This is what I have tried which is not printing the name

```
String child=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='cphPageContent_ChildrensInfo1_repChildren_hasEnrollments_0']//a[@class='editStudent']")).getText();

        System.out.println(child);
```

Thank You for your time and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try getting the innertext.

```
String child=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td#cphPageContent_ChildrensInfo1_repChildren_hasEnrollments_0 a")).getAttribute("innerText")
```